# How to create a hidden item in flex-mobile like the hidden element in HTML?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

In HTML we can create an element of type hidden, is it possible to create a similar element in **flex-mobile** ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is no need for an equivalent of the 'hidden' element in a Flex app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide elements from displaying on screen by using the visible property and setting it to false

You can prevent elements from being included in the layout scheme of their container by using the includeInLayout property and setting it to false

You can also hide/show elements based on states.

Since you haven't provided any context for what you want to do, it is tough to direct you to a specific approach.

Comment: In fact I want to use the value of a sharedobject in the `url` attribute of my `HTTPService` which is declared in the `Declarations` section : I receive a warning message stating that "the data binding may not see the attributions to the sharedobject" at the line of the HTTPService ! So I want to get the sharedobject's value from a hidden element.

Comment: @pheromix That is a completely different issue than the one you described in this question,